# Is a pure-JS raw RSA implementation secure for transferring information?

Tags: javascript, rsa

Assuming I have the RSA forge (javascript) library, does the pure-RSA implementation work for information transferring? I know that the forge library has the keysystem and everything, but I want to know if this standalone RSA implementation is secure.

Comment: Secure against what?

Comment: client side? no ... for many reasons.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be secure if used correctly, however, using raw RSA correctly is a difficult task. Because it is easy to make a critical mistake, using low level primitives is discouraged and considered bad practice. You should get a high level library with simple API if possible.

If you can't, make sure you read up on RSA padding and all the peculiarities of RSA, such as it being dangerous to encrypt the same message with many RSA public keys.